# GAE/J remote_api?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

The server part of the Remote API that App Engine uses can be installed in the Java version as well, so that you can use for example the bulkloader.py utility to backup data.

But is there also a Java client for accessing this API (or is that only available for Python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available now: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi.html

Answer (score 2):

No Java client is available yet, sorry.